# Query to join 4 tables to get employee assigned to projects outside of their dept

Tags: sql

```
DEPARTMENT(ID integer PRIMARY KEY, 
                        NAME text);

EMPLOYEE(ID integer PRIMARY KEY, 
                       NAME text, 
                       DEPARTMENT_ID integer,
                        FOREIGN KEY(DEPARTMENT_ID) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(ID));
        
PROJECT(ID integer PRIMARY KEY, 
                    NAME text, 
                    DEPARTMENT_ID integer,
                    FOREIGN KEY(DEPARTMENT_ID) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(ID));   

SCHEDULE(EMPLOYEE_ID integer, 
                        PROJECT_ID integer,
                        FOREIGN KEY(EMPLOYEE_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(ID),
                        FOREIGN KEY(PROJECT_ID) REFERENCES PROJECT(ID));
```

Write a query to print the names of employees with the names of the project they are assigned (or have worked) outside of their department.

this is what I have tried so far-

```
select distinct e.Name, p.Name
    from SCHEDULE s
    left join EMPLOYEE e on e.id = s.EMPLOYEE_ID
    inner join DEPARTMENT d on d.id = e.department_id
    left join PROJECT p on p.department_id = d.id
    left join p.id = s.PROJECT_ID
```

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Why have you tagged this with MySQL and MongoDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like home work.

You don't need the department table as long you don't need the name.

Second you onpy choose those projects that have not the employees Departmentid

And finally you can use inner join, , because you are only interested in schedule, that have a project and employee

```
SELECT distinct e.Name, p.Name
FROM SCHEDULE s
    INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE e on e.id = s.EMPLOYEE_ID
    INNER JOIN PROJECT p ON p.department_id = d.id AND p.DEPARTMENT_ID <> e.DEPARTMENT_ID
```